# Is what GitHub is doing here a good practice?

Tags: github

If you view this URL, you'll see that GitHub is posting all sorts of technical information. Is this a good practice so that users can email info to you about bugs, etc?

http://waitdownload.github.com/cheetahtemplate-cheetah-v2.4.2-0-gd20b523.zip

It's at least a good design for an error page.

Comment: It's probably *more* acceptable on GitHub than, say, Facebook - users are likely to understand it's an error page on a site with such a technical audience. Someone from the more general public would probably be confused by all the stuff listed there.

Comment: I just checked the page: are they serious about using webrick?

Comment: @bandi I Googled that and found this: http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2010/01/10/webrick-escape-sequence-injection/ (I wouldn't use webrick after reading that).

Comment: They might have just messed up something with the deployment. Webrick is more like a testing server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Leaving detailed error pages is certainly making malicious attackers' job much-much easier. I would think that security is more important than possible bug reports.

Comment: btw. I would suggest to notify first the admins of github and publish later